# monacaで「iosrtc」cordovaプラグインのビルドエラー

Tags: javascript, html, monaca, cordova

monacaを利用しているものですが、IOSでWebRTCを使ったアプリ作成を行いたいと思っています。
しかし内部ブラウザであるWKWebViewでは使えないことがわかり、別途cordovaプラグインを使用することにしました。
見つけたものが「iosrtc(https://github.com/BasqueVoIPMafia/cordova-plugin-iosrtc)」
というもので、プラグインをアップロード、有効化して試しにカスタムデバッカーでビルドしようとしました。
しかしここでエラーが出てしまい、先に進めない状況になってしまっています。

```
Remove DerivedData files...

Remove IB Support files...
Change Xcode Version to 9
Build Error: Error: Sandbox Exec Error: [ ** ARCHIVE FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    CompileSwift normal arm64 /tmp/monaca/5bb44c3ee788859048201c66/project/platforms/ios/testcamera/Plugins/cordova-plugin-iosrtc/iosrtcPlugin.swift
    CompileSwift normal arm64 /tmp/monaca/5bb44c3ee788859048201c66/project/platforms/ios/testcamera/Plugins/cordova-plugin-iosrtc/PluginRTCTypes.swift
    CompileSwiftSources normal arm64 com.apple.xcode.tools.swift.compiler
(3 failures)
Error: Error code 65 for command: xcodebuild with args: -xcconfig,/private/tmp/monaca/5bb44c3ee788859048201c66/project/platforms/ios/cordova/build-debug.xcconfig,-workspace,testcamera.xcworkspace,-scheme,testcamera,-configuration,Debug,-destination,generic/platform=iOS,-archivePath,testcamera.xcarchive,archive,CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=/private/tmp/monaca/5bb44c3ee788859048201c66/project/platforms/ios/build/device,SHARED_PRECOMPS_DIR=/private/tmp/monaca/5bb44c3ee788859048201c66/project/platforms/ios/build/sharedpch
 ]
```

swiftを使用しているようなので,config.xmlに

```
<platform name="ios">
  <preference name="ios-XCBuildConfiguration-SWIFT_VERSION" value="4"/>
</platform>
```

を追記しました。
とりあえず、「iosrtc」cordovaプラグイン無しでビルドをしてみたところ成功したため、証明書関係は問題ないようです。
(それなのにエラーコード 65　が出ているのが気になりますが...)

ご教授お願い致します。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cordova-plugin-iosrtcのドキュメント

https://github.com/BasqueVoIPMafia/cordova-plugin-iosrtc/blob/master/docs/Building.md

を読むと書いてありますが、このプラグインはただ組み込んだだけでは動作せず、その後、手動でXcodeに設定を行う必要があるとされています。

このドキュメントも、どうも古くて不十分のようなのですが、自分が手元で確認した限りでは、

1. Swiftのバージョンを3.0にする
2. Bridgingヘッダーを設定する

の2つが必要のようです。

基本的に、Monacaでは、手動で設定が必要なプラグインは正式な対応はしていないため、このプラグインは利用することが出来ません。

そのため、プラグインを改修するか、もしくは、補助スクリプト（フックスクリプト）を利用してなんとかするしかないと思います。

ここでは、試しに補助スクリプトを使って次の方法を行ってみました。一応、ビルドには成功しました。

1. Swiftのバージョンについては、質問者さんの方法で設定しますが、Monacaでは内部でXcode 9系が利用されているため、3.0は使えないので、3.3とします。
2. Bridging-Header.hは、Cordova 7系では変更出来ないため、フックスクリプトで対応します。(なお、Cordova 9系から、これらの設定が出来るように予定されています）

具体的には、次の1.2.を行います。

1. config.xmlを編集し、`<platform name="ios">`の配下に次を組み込む

   ```
   <preference name="ios-XCBuildConfiguration-SWIFT_VERSION" value="3.3"/>
   <hook type="after_prepare" src="res/after_prepare_ios.js"/>
   ```
2. resフォルダの下に、`after_prepare_ios.js`ファイルを作り、次のコードを書き込む。

   ```
   // This is a JavaScript file
   var path = require('path');
   var fs = require('fs');
   module.exports = function(context) {
     var projectRoot = context.opts.projectRoot;
     var pathAPI = path.resolve(projectRoot, 'platforms', 'ios', 'cordova', 'Api.js');
     var API = require(pathAPI);
     var api = new API('ios');

     var src = path.resolve(projectRoot, 'plugins', 'cordova-plugin-iosrtc', 'src', 'cordova-plugin-iosrtc-Bridging-Header.h');
     var dist = path.resolve(api.locations.xcodeCordovaProj, 'Bridging-Header.h');

     console.log('-- copy file ' + src + ' to ' + dist);
     fs.copyFileSync(src, dist);

   };
   ```

この2. については、何をしているのかよくわからないかも知れませんが、要は、プラグインが内包している`cordova-plugin-iosrtc-Bridging-Header.h`ファイルを強制的にコピーして、Cordovaのブリッジングヘッダーである`Bridging-Header.h`に上書きしています。

組み込んだプラグインは、やや古いもののようなので、ビルドが成功したとしても、期待された動作をするかどうかまでは分かりませんが、ご参考になれば幸いです。

Comment: ご回答誠にありがとうございます。
ドキュメントを読んだところ自分も書き換える必要がありそうだなとは思っていたのですが、変更できる環境ではないためあきらめていました...
ご教授していただいた内容でビルドすることができました！ありがとうございました。

Comment: 無事動作したようで良かったです！

Comment: streamを取得して見ましたがvideoelement.srcObject = streamで再生されないですね...

Comment: こちら
https://github.com/BasqueVoIPMafia/cordova-plugin-iosrtc/blob/master/docs/iosrtc.md
にあるように、iosrtcのAPIを呼ぶ必要があると思います。
別の質問を立てて、試したコードを記載するのが良いかと思います。

Comment: ドキュメントを見直して作成したら何とか表示できたのでこのままやってみたいと思います。ありがとうございました。